# Command-line arguments vs File properties (*.properties) vs System Properties (-D) in Java

Tags: java, command-line-interface, command-line-arguments, ini

There is a number of way one can pass arguments to Java application. Among them are:

1. Command-line arguments
2. Properties files (`properties`-style)
3. System properties (passed via `-D` option)
4. System environment variables

Ideologically, when should one prefer ones against the others? 
For example, if one has a lot of parameters to pass to the application, is there any reason to favor command-line parameters over *.properties file?

Or, for example, one can easily access System variable from any class deep down the stack (as opposed to CLI, which is only accessible in `main`). Should one prefer using System properties over CLI only because of the ease of access?

Comment: Additionally to both answers: you can also combine all of these. For example you could, with increasing strength, first check a configuration file, then an environment variable finally a switch. This way you can override global application configuration by local switches or environment variables.

Answer (score 4):

Depends on deployment needs to answer some of these.

Command line params: is nice when you have other processes spawning your application and you want to control those parameters from the calling process. An example would be CRON spawning it.

Files: I don't like ini style...you're stuck on Windows. Prefer .properties files that you can load with the Properties class if you want something very simple. Or you can go with XML. Files also give you choice on file placements, relative to application is nice for deployment, and some people also like throwing them someplace global like /etc

Environment variables: These have their place although it makes deployment a bit more complicated. I'd only use this if the environment affects the parameters of your application. Meaning, your application will act differently or need to be configured differently based on the OS, machine, etc.

Preference is subjective and can depend on the type of application, deployment, system, etc.

Comment: Small addition: files are used to store information that is not changed in time, i.e "static" values. Command line is better for "dynamic" values. Complex application may use a mix of these styles (depending on deployment needs, as @Nick said).

Answer (score 0):

Well, coming to configurations, each programmer has its own idea on how's the right way to do... As usual it depends on a whole lot of things.

I use to deal with this choice in this way: if it's something like an enviroment var, (something similar to $PATH or $SHELL), and can/must be set by the caller (another program or a startup script), it goes straight in System.Properties via -D switch.

If it's something else, then it goes straight to property file (and actually how it's loaded is not really important, there are several ways to do it, each with pros and cons, my fav is loading from classpath, but is just a matter of taste).

I try to keep in System.Properties just minimal, really important things, if it's a big configuration, better use Properties or XML or even better database tables, but again, it depends on the complexity of your application (HelloWorld with a DB is plain overkill ^^).